# init structuremap

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, controller, structuremap

I've got problem of parameterless constructor of controller, in order to solve it, I'm going to use StructureMap

I add this class

```
public class StructureMapControllerFactory : DefaultControllerFactory
{
    public override IController CreateController(RequestContext requestContext, string controllerName)
    {
        try
        {
            string key = controllerName.ToLowerInvariant();
            return ObjectFactory.GetNamedInstance<IController>(key);
        }
        catch (StructureMapException ex)
        {
            //Use the default logic.
            return base.CreateController(requestContext, controllerName);
        }
    }
}
```

And I add

```
ControllerBuilder.Current.SetControllerFactory(new StructureMapControllerFactory());
```

to Application_Start() at Global.asax.cs

But I've got error, probably because I don't initialize StructureMap
How can I properly initialize this for using ONLY ControllerFactory?

Comment: What version of MVC are you using?

Comment: If the constructor is parameter less, why do you need StructureMap? Is sm injecting property dependencies? Is it managing object life cycle?

Comment: @JoshuaFlanagan I haven't parameterless constructor. That's why I have problem. My constructor accept IRepository as parameters and as result I need controllers' factory which allow use controllers' constructor with parameters without parameterless contstructor

Answer (score 1):

You need to register your dependencies somewhere. There are several ways to do this that you can read about in the structuremap documentation.

There is also a NuGet package named StructureMap.MVC3 that got everything working out of the box according to the project site. I have not tested it my self.

Here is a naive example with a website with one controller

Controller

```
public class MyController : Controller
{
    private readonly IRepository repository;

    public MyController(IRepository repository)
    {
        this.repository = repository;
    }

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        ViewBag.Message = repository.GetData();

        return View();
    }
}
```

Global.asax

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

    ObjectFactory.Initialize(a => a.For<IRepository>().Use<Repository>());
    ControllerBuilder.Current.SetControllerFactory(new MyControllerFactory());

    RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
    RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
}
```

In my ControllerFactory

```
protected override IController GetControllerInstance(System.Web.Routing.RequestContext requestContext, Type controllerType)
{
    return (Controller)ObjectFactory.GetInstance(controllerType);
}
```

[Configuring StructureMap](http://docs.structuremap.net/ConfiguringStructureMap.htm)

[StructureMap.MVC3](https://github.com/webadvanced/Structuremap-MVC3)